# Get appSettings key value in Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, config

I am trying to get a value from a config file on multiple computers.

Here is the file on each computer.... I am trying to get \gm107a\Updates\QC into a csv file along with the computer name.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="updatelocation" value="\\gm107a\Updates\QC"/>
    <add key="filename" value="QualityControl.exe"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I found this to start me going: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/268e03cb-1248-456f-bc89-ecc31cb0489b/powershell-script-to-read-xml-data-from-multiple-remote-computers then found this [getting app.config elements in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15939218/getting-app-config-elements-in-powershell) and tried putting it together.... Remember I am brand new lol.

Here is what I have so far:

```
function vert {
$hostnamenodes = get-content C:\Scripts\Computers.txt

foreach ($hostname in $hostnamenodes) {
[xml]$xml = Get-Content \\$hostname\C$\Drivers\Version.config
            #Add hostrecord to array
            $MasterArray = New-Object psobject -Property @{
            "ServerName" = $hostname
            "updatelocation" = $xml.SelectNodes('//add[@key="updatelocation"]/@value')[0].'#text'

}
write-output $masterarray
} }
vert | select servername,updatelocation | Export-Csv QA.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Here is the error I get:

```
Unable to index into an object of type System.Xml.XPathNodeList.
At C:\Scripts\get-content.ps1:13 char:88
+             "updatelocation" = $xml.SelectNodes('//add[@key="updatelocation"]/@value')[ <<<< 0].'#text'
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (0:Int32) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotIndex
```

After editing my script with the solution below I now get the following error:

Here is the new error I am getting:

```
Unable to index into an object of type System.Xml.XPathNodeList.
At C:\Scripts\get-content.ps1:9 char:92
+                 "updatelocation" = $xml.SelectNodes('//add[@key="updatelocation"]/@value')[ <<<< 0].'#text'}
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (0:Int32) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotIndex
```

Answer (score 5):

Ok tried it a different way and it works!!!! Yay! Thanks for your help with error checking!!!

```
"updatelocation" = $xml.configuration.appSettings.add | Where-Object { $_.key -eq 'updatelocation' } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty value
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine with the supplied Version.config example (just missing a closing ">" at the end. From the error it looks you're hitting an empty Version.config file or a file with missing "updatelocation" key. Should do some error checking...

```
function vert {
    $hostnamenodes = get-content C:\Scripts\Computers.txt
    foreach ($hostname in $hostnamenodes) {
        if (test-path \\$hostname\C$\Drivers\Version.config){
            [xml]$xml = Get-Content \\$hostname\C$\Drivers\Version.config
            if ($xml.SelectNodes('//add[@key="updatelocation"]/@value')) {
                $MasterArray = New-Object psobject -Property @{
                "ServerName" = $hostname
                "updatelocation" = $xml.SelectNodes('//add[@key="updatelocation"]/@value')[0].'#text'}
            } else {
                write-error "Key `"updatelocation`" does not exist"
            }
        } else {
            write-error "File `"Version.config`" does not exist"
        }
        write-output $masterarray
    }  
}

vert | select servername,updatelocation | Export-Csv QA.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Ah didn't copy the whole config file here and now I am adding >. The config file listed is copied and pasted from one of the computers in the computers.txt and the path is correct. Any other ideas?

Comment: Did you change the script to include the checks? Script itself is fine, but you will get en error when: Remote computer is not there, Computer is not defined in DNS, You do not have rights to access the computer, The file you're looking for is not on the computer, The file is there, but has unexpected content, etc...

Comment: Ok I ran the checks and got the following:
Missing closing '}' in statement block.
At C:\Scripts\get-content.ps1:35 char:1
+  <<<< 
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (CloseBraceToken:TokenId) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEndCurlyBrace

Comment: thank you very much for all your help. I've learned so much. Unfortunately, I am now getting another error. since I don't have room to put it in a comment I am going to edit my question with the new error.

Comment: So, we are back to the same error. Try adding this line write-host (Get-Content D:\Scripts\Powershell\Sniplets\Version.config | out-string) after line [xml]$xml = ... This way, you should be able to see what was in the file that caused script to fail.